# How to get number of clicks, impressions that I would get for my Ad Group Budget?

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api

I need to know whether can I get number of clicks, and impressions that I would receive for a specific budget using Google Ad Word API. Here I am using PHP library.

For example, if I choose a budget of $50 for an Ad Group, I need to get estimate number of clicks, and impressions that I would get for the budget of $50.

And can I do payment to Google Ads via Google Ad Word API ? As I have integrated API to my website am I able to access the Payment method via my website.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question.

Comment: I go through with code - **Get keyword traffic estimates** as shown  in following link and tried it.
(https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/optimization#estimate-keyword-traffic)

And it gives me following result. I have set Maximum CPC as 2000000

`Results for the keyword with text 'land for sale' and match type 'BROAD':
Estimated average CPC: 355840.00
Estimated ad position: 5.81
Estimated daily clicks: 141.94
Estimated daily cost: 10281407.00
Estimated daily Impressions: 619775235.00`

so I want to know how much this is correct with what I am accepting.